# System Message limit of 48 hours bypassed for per-site-meta election announcement?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, system-message

It's been 48 hours since elections started, which means that the banner goes away. However, I noticed that on Gaming Meta, the banner is still up. Checking the data says it isn't going to expire until February 15th, which is almost two weeks from now.

I can't check the dates on other sites, but I did notice that they also still have the system message on their per-site-metas.

---

I did a bit of experimentation. Which knocked our meta banner out of commission, but you can still see it on [Web Apps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com) and on [AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/). It seems that we're still barred from setting it longer than 48 hours on those places, but the original message set by Community is allowed to stand for longer. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main site has a system message that lasts for the first 2 days of each phase.

The meta site has a single system message for the duration of the election (see when the election page says the election is over...).  Notice the general wording on the child meta compared to the phase-specific wording on the main site.

Yes, it is intentional. (:

Comment: Thanks, Rebecca! Now, considering it is intentional... any chance of repair for the one on Gaming that I obliterated?